# Not necessarily conditionally independent = dependent?

Tags: probability, independence, conditional-independence, d-separation

After concluding the d-separation procedure (ancestral graph -> moral graph -> removing directed links), I am left with two nodes that are connected and a conclusion that they are "not necessarily conditionally independent". Does that mean they are dependent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it means they are not necessarily conditionally independent.

There are many more possible joint distributions of variables than there are graphs, so each graph represents many joint distributions.  If there is no edge between two nodes then you know *all* the possible joint distributions represented by the graph have a conditional independence.  If there is an edge, all you know is that some of the possible joint distributions represented by the graph have conditional dependence.  It could happen that the conditional dependence just happens to cancel out.

Suppose that $X$ affects $Y$ positively, and $X$ and $Y$ both affect $Z$ positively.  Conditioning on $Z$ will induce a negative correlation between $X$ and $Y$, and it is conceivable that this negative correlation exactly cancels the effect of $X$ on $Y$ and leaves them exactly independent. There's no way to tell this from the structure of the graph, so the graph has to have an edge between $X$ and $Y$.

The *faithfulness* assumption is that there are no conditional independence relations other than those forced by the structure of the graph; these cancellations are assumed not to happen and your linked nodes are conditionally dependent. It's a popular additional assumption.